# Sharing entity and data across databases / entitymanagers

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently building a huge Symfony2 project, which consists on a central application (let's call it "Main", and different standalone projects, mostly on Symfony2 too (let's call these "Satellites").

The Main project will have its own database, and each Satellite too. However, the Main project will manage some critical data (users, roles, etc...), and this data needs to be available on **each Satellite**. This means some kind of "replication" from certain entities to a list of databases (managed by other Symfony2 apps, or not)

The part that is actually working is the mapping. I have a Bundle which provides the User and Role model classes. Other bundles just have to extend those classes (*FOSUserBundle* style), and the mapping will be performed correctly.

I am actually struggling with the "replication" from the Main project to each Satellite's database. Basically the perfect workflow would be:

1. A User or Role is added / removed / updated on Main
2. A service loops through a list of database connections
3. re-executing the query / queries involved in step 1. on each other database connection. **This implies not only using other entity managers, but mostly generating plain SQL queries to execute on servers where Satellites are not Symfony2 apps**

I can hook on the "onFlush" event of Doctrine, and retrieve a list of entities that are going to be updated / persisted / removed. The part where i'm completely lost is the 3.

Is it even possible ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you actually [replicate the database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)? You'll end up with sync errors if one or more of the connections or queries fails trying to run remote queries (you'd probably be better off with a [command bus](https://github.com/SimpleBus/SymfonyBridge) too). There's also SymmetricDS, which is specifically for these types of things. There's a free community version.

Comment: You could use a message or job queue. For example, you could create a job using JMSJobQueueBundle (http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/usage) that could be used to eventually send (or fail to send, without killing your application) commands to the external apps.

Comment: @qooplmao that seems quite interesting, but how would you deal with a job that says "I created / updated / removed those entities, replicate it everywhere", given I only have the connection credentials for each database where the replication should be ?

Comment: I would deal with it the same way that I would deal with it directly, but just trigger the update via a command (you can create the job in the same listener/call that you would handle things directly). The only benefit in doing with jobs is that you can pass it off to outside of the current process, meaning that if it failed on the "satellite" then it could notify you of the failure rather than killing the whole process. Although, this situation would only work if you are OK with eventual consistency as opposed to everything needing to present on all apps (main and satellite) at all times.

Comment: Actually i did something more "stupid", that is moving my shared entities into a separate bundle, add each database configuration to my config.yml so that I have X entity managers (where X is the number of databases where the data should be replicated). Then on each entity persist/flush/remove I call a listener that will update on the rest of the entity managers. I am now trying to do the last step !

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation in one of my project, we have Main and Satellite application,
all required datas hold in main and all applications talking each other via APIs, also in satellite application we have custom user provider which is authenticate users from main server. You could follow this way. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: The problem resides in the fact that the applications won't talk to each other. Only Satellite needs to have the same tables that Main (some of them), because we will be using foreign keys between the tables of Main and some of the Satellite ones